# Delegating Domain Model Behaviour outside of Entity

Tags: entity, domain-driven-design, behavior, service-layer

I’m trying to implement domain driven design (DDD) whilst at the same time using SOLID design principles but had the following question:

If my domain entities contain only state and the behavioural methods associated with them within the ubiquitous language are placed into separate classes does this classify as either an anemic or rich domain model?

For example, instead of having this on my entity:

```
class Order
{
    public virtual void Ship();
}
```

I’ve actually factored this out into a separate OO class:

```
class Shipper
{
    public virtual void Ship(Order order);
}
```

From my point of view this is still inside the “model” rather than the service/application layer, therefore I believe this would still be a rich domain model.

I may however delegate the call of retrieving my order and shipping it inside the service layer as follows:

```
class OrderService
{
    //private member construction ommitted for brevity
    Repository _repository;
    ShipOrder _shipper;
    public void Ship(int orderId)
    {
        Order order = _repository.GetOrder(orderId);
        _shipper.Ship(order);
    }
}
```

The reason for NOT implementing the behavioural logic inside the domain entity is that implementing it would go against the single responsibility principle, in that the responsibility of my entity is to maintain and store state within my domain.  However, my opinion on this is could be subjective.

Comment: Ask yourself what it means to ship an order? How does it affect the state of the system? What invariants needs to be enforced and what other components are at play in the shipping process (e.g. external system)? At the end it might become clear whether you should use a domain service or place the behavior on the AR.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, Shipper and Order are two different concepts in your domain (non-technically speaking). If that is the case, **separating them is the right choice**, because you should design your domain model as close to the real world as possible.

Answer (score 0):

What is a shipper? Do your domain experts talk about shippers a lot? Do different shippers ship orders differently? I doubt someone working in a store would talk about a shipper. at best they would talk about the employee who ships the order.

I think separating them 'might' be fine but then shipper would be a domain service. DDD is more about lowering the communication barrier than about folling the single responsiblity principle. In DDD i doubht it would fit into your domain model for the simple reason a domain expert wouldn't talk about it. They would talking about shipping an order.

what you might do is this

```
class Order {
      public void Ship() {
          IOCContainer.Resolve<IShippingService>.ShipOrder(this);
      }
 }
```

Now you could put all the actual logic inside the shipping service (which implements the IShippingService interface). This also solves the single responsibility principle. If you read 'uncle bob's comments about the single responsiblity principle it's not so much about doing just 1 single thing, but having 1 reason to change. https://blog.8thlight.com/uncle-bob/2014/05/08/SingleReponsibilityPrinciple.html

If i implement my shipping logic like this i would expect this part of my code to have no reason to change at al, (since the change in the shipping process wouldn't be located here but in the ShippingService).

This way you could combine DDD and SOLID.

Comment: what can i do to improve this answer?